# Difference between `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> mybranch` and `git remote add upstream URL`

Tags: git, github, upstream-branch

I have a repo in my account which is not forked from anywhere. But when I tried to do git pull in one of the branches, I got this message:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> mybranch
```

Doing `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/mybranch mybranch` solved the problem.
But how is this different from `git remote add upstream URL`?

Any suggestion gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also related: [Why do I need to do `--set-upstream` all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6089294/2745495) and [Creating new git branch. What is the point of git remote add?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57713710/2745495)

Comment: I am seeing the answers that u have mentioned

Comment: Now, I have some understanding of the concept.